UK Visa from Madagascar for Crewmember joining a ship
I'm from Madagascar. I'm a crewmember of a vessel, and I'm going to join a cruise ship in Southampton port. What kind of visa should I apply for? I will not stay in the UK; I'm just joining this vessel.

Have you asked your employer? There are special rules for sailors going to their ship, I guess your case is like that and your employer should have handled this before.

As a Madagascan citizen needing to clear UK Immigration to join the ship in Southampton, a Visitor visa is required.
Source: Seafarers, and UK Visa Requirements

I don’t think either of the pages you linked to agree. OP needs a Seafarer’s book issued by a country in the given list, but does not need to be a national of said country. Now, don’t ask me how they get that book…
